# One website's login/logout affects another website on same server

Tags: php, session

I am developing two dynamic websites for a Final Year College Project. Sometimes while tabbed browsing and having that both websites open in the same browser at the same time simultaneously, the following happens.

I use sessions for tracking the login and just destroy the session at the end (logout) to logout the system; because of this "session_destroy();" my another site running on "localhost" causes to logout.

How to overcome this problem?

Don't suggest destroying session variables specifically (i.e. `unset($_SESSION['usename'])`. Please suggest an appropriate way, I will be very thankful. ☺

Comment: Are they on the same domain?

Comment: I think the problem is that both sites are sharing the 'localhost' name. Create address aliases on your computer, and then set up Apache to have separate vhosts for each one. Your two sites will then use separate sessions. Or, set your vhosts up using separate ports, that'll do it too.

Comment: This is not overly surprising if they are on the same domain... Use VHOSTs to separate the domains. You can create hosts records to point site1.localhost to 127.0.0.1, and site2.localhost to 127.0.0.1 as well; but the virtual host will figure out where the source code is and run from there. This will prevent the sessions storing over each other

Comment: @halfer : Address aliasing may solve the problem temporarily.But what is the best practice to do....??

Comment: Best practice is to never have two independent sites running inside the same domain namespace (subdomains would also solve it)

Comment: @Vikram, my comment would be best practice, I think. You're running two sites from the same domain/port, and thus PHP treats them as the same site. Change the domain and/or the port and the two sessions will work separately.

Comment: @halfer why not use the in-built path configuration rather than playing with vhosts?

Comment: @halfer & Trent : Ok...I will alias the host onwards...

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, yes, I forgot you could do that (upvoted). However, it adds another configuration step to sites when setting them up (either in production or on a development machine). I prefer one vhost = one application, it just makes things easier. Hence, I have around 40 entries in my dev machine `/etc/hosts`, and a good number of vhost files in my Apache config folder.

Comment: @halfer, - in this instance it may well be a simple alternative, but when talking about best practices, it's probably best to think of options not platform dependent, so that these two sites could change servers and stay on the same domain, but only PHP code needs to be changed rather than core server configurations.

Comment: Vikram's choice at the end of the day, a number of choices available to you now.

Comment: @Smokey, not sure I fully understand your point. Can you expand on that a bit? `:)`

Comment: @halfer - if the 2 sites get moved to another server, for live testing and still on the same domain, the same sessions issue will arise. Depending on the server, the ability to modify the vhosts file may not be there - at which point, my solution will need to be used anyway. It's more portable and easier than new coders learning how to create a vhost.

Comment: what if there are 2 websites hosted in the same server space (tracert gives same IP address) ? What could be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using prefix (i use in my websit) and destroying sessions only with spec. prefix

**Website one**

```
define("prefix", "firstweb_");
$_SESSION[prefix.'logged'] = true;
```

**Website Two**

```
define("prefix", "secondweb_");
$_SESSION[prefix.'logged'] = true;
```

**Website one logout**

```
destroy_session();
```

**Function**

```
function destroy_session()
{
  foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
  {
    if(preg_match('/^'.prefix.'/', $value))
      unset($_SESSION['key']);
  }
}
```

Comment: But If someone uses session_destroy() in their website which is on the same server then it will affect our sessions and all the sessions will get destroyed regardless of the prefix...

Comment: I guess this would be the solution if the OP cannot use vhosts, +1. But vhosts are still preferable I think!

Comment: Here is the first solution that came to my mind, so it may not be the best.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the cookie paths are set properly per website:

```
session_set_cookie_params(600,'/website1/','localhost');
session_start();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Sessions will default their path parameter to just '/', hence this override being required when working locally.