# Why PHP session of one directory is affecting other?

Tags: php

I have two PHP based application which are under same parent directory. They both have login mechanism installed. The session variable which I am using to store has the same name in both the applications. Say,

```
$_SESSION["uid"]
```

Now when I log out from one of the application (i.e. basically clearing the session variables) it automatically clears the session variable of the other application.

How can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: Are the two applications using the same index names in the `$_SESSION` array?

Comment: You can try different browser in order to keep session for other application.

Comment: How you do clear the session variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One website's login/logout affects another website on same server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393718/one-websites-login-logout-affects-another-website-on-same-server)

Comment: Set session cookie path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `session_destroy();` in PHP, know that `session_destroy();`  removes all the variables in `$_SESSION`  when it is invoked. Even if your web application uses two different variable names, those variables are still in `$_SESSION`, which is lost the moment `session_destroy();` is invoked.

My advice would be to add a prefix to your `$_SESSION` variables and make a separate function for clearing those prefixed `$_SESSION` variables rather than calling `session_destroy();`

This can be done by adding the following after `session_start();` of your webapp.

For webapp 1 :

```
// Web App 1
define("prefix", "WebApp1");
//SET YOUR SESSION VARIABLES LIKE THIS
$_SESSION[prefix.'authenticated'] = true;
```

For webapp 2:

```
// Web App 2
define("prefix", "WebApp2");
//SET YOUR SESSION VARIABLES LIKE THIS
$_SESSION[prefix.'authenticated'] = true;
```

Then make a separate function for destroying our prefixed session variables instead of `session_destroy();`

```
function destroy_session($prefix){

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {

if(preg_match('/^'.$prefix.'/', $value))
  unset($_SESSION['key']);
  }
}
```

And then call this function in your web apps instead of `session_destroy();`

```
destroy_session(prefix);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the session parameters for both the apps along with setting the session name before you start the session. This way when you end the session, it will only affect the one of them.

Code would look like -
App1

```
$sessionName = session_name("appName1");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/app1', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

App2

```
$sessionName = session_name("appName2");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/app2', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

More info on the above functions can be found on the following links -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php